# Set UIButton image in interface builder / storyboard

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I have a View Controller which I add a round rect button to in storyboard.
The application is working well and I also connected the button to a segue using the storyboard.
I am trying to set a custom image for this button for it on&off states.
How do i access this button and set it's properties? (in this case the on & off images)

Comment: I think this would give the right solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150614/different-image-when-button-from-storyboard-tapped

Answer (score 18):

Here is a screenshot :

[image: UIButton]

Set your button type to Custom, and change the image for all the states (choose a state, then choose the image, repeat for each state).