# Different image when button from storyboard tapped

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

I have a button that I want to use a different background image when in highlighted state, normally I would use something like

```
[buttonObject setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonDown.png"] 
                        forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

But the button is in a .storyboard file, not code.
What should I use in this situation?

Comment: You can still connect `buttonObject` to your IBOutlet and use your code.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can set up different properties for different states in IB too, by selecting the state from the drop down menu:

[image]

If you want to do it in code, you have to set up an outlet and set the images in `awakeFromNib`.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

To connect the outlet, you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-drag from the button to your File Owner (probably a view controller) and select the outlet defined above.

Then you can access the button in your code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonDown.png"] 
                      forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Comment: +1 for the non-code config set up and the screenshot. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using outlets?

[Configuring the View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html) from Apple doc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Because you can do it via storyboard: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12150649/1442541